# simple fbml fb:login-button is not rendering in ie6

Tags: facebook, fbml

The following codes works in FF and Chrome, but IE6 does not render the connect button.

What am I missing here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0     Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<fb:login-button>Login button</fb:login-button>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function(){ 
    FB.Facebook.init("API_KEY", "/xd_receiver.htm"); 
}); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you replace `API_KEY` with your actual API key?

Comment: ofcourse.. as mentioned, the button appears in FF and Chrome without a problem. 
This applies to the rest of my application aswell, all fbml tags are working and rendering fine in FF but not in IE6.

The above code is the most basic example and still it will not render in IE6.

Comment: How did you test this? I read online that IETester fails to render it correctly, even though a real IE6 would work.

Comment: I am having the same issue with and it seems that there is a problem with FB_RequireFeatures in IE6. I have not found anything else, but IE6 does throw an Javascript error "Object Expected" when that function is there, while the error is absent when the function is not there. I cannot debug IE6 any further.

Comment: There's also an issue if you happen to be testing on a non-80 port, as the JavaScript SDK uses window.location.hostname instead of window.location.host.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with the Maxthon browser and not the straight forward IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the javascript to this one:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=261463080590982";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```